# Can I modify contents in Jupyter Notebook output cell?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook (FKA Ipython notebook), I have a cell which I ran for a long time until I got some text result in the output cell. However I found there is a small typo in the output that I would like to change without rerunning the cell again. Is there a way to modify contents in output cells?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .ipynb files are just text files in JSON looking format.  You can search for the typo and change it.

I suggest you fix the typo in the input cell in case you run it again and then save the notebook.  Then open the .ipynb file and search for the error in an output cell and fix it.  Save it as text and reopen in Jupyter.  It will have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Jupyter notebook file in a notepad and change the output as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

No, the output is entirely dependent on the input cell, so you will need to modify the input and run it again.